# Oracle Update Batching Models - Using both batching models in same application

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11gr2

Oracle JDBC supports two distinct models for update batching: Standard Batching and Oracle Specific Batching.

According to oracle 11g JDBC Developer Guide, in any single application, you can use one model or the other, **but not both. Oracle JDBC driver will throw exceptions when you mix these**.

In my standalone application, the above statement does not hold true. I want to know if I am missing something.

In my application I create a OracleDataSource and do the following

```
    connection = datasource.getConnection();
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update CAR set CAR_NAME=?, OBJECT_VERSION=? where CAR_ID=?");
    for(Car car : cars) {
       preparedStatement.setString(1, car.getName());
       preparedStatement.setInt(2, car.getVersion() + 1);
       preparedStatement.setLong(3, car.getId());
       preparedStatement.addBatch();
    }
```

`System.out.println("Update Batch : " + Arrays.toString(preparedStatement.executeBatch()));


 for(Car car : cars) {
     car.setName("v car " + car.getId());
 }


//Oracle Update Batching 

connection.setAutoCommit(false);

PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
          connection.prepareStatement("update CAR set CAR_NAME=?, OBJECT_VERSION=? where CAR_ID=?");

//Change batch size for this statement to 3
((OraclePreparedStatement)preparedStatement).setExecuteBatch (10);

   for(Car car : cars) {
      preparedStatement.setString(1, car.getName());
      preparedStatement.setInt(2, car.getVersion() + 1);
      preparedStatement.setLong(3, car.getId());
      System.out.println("Execute Update Count " + preparedStatement.executeUpdate());
   }

   System.out.println("Update Count : " + ((OraclePreparedStatement)preparedStatement).sendBatch()); // JDBC sends the queued request

   connection.commit();

   preparedStatement.close();`

The above code runs well and I could see both the update batches using different batching models getting executed well. Is there anything which I missed out or my interpretation of jdbc developer guide is incorrect?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they write the truth :-)
But this aply to **one** instance of PreparedStatement

I looked at decompile sources of OraclePreparedStatement:

```
public void addBatch() throws SQLException {
  synchronized(connection){
    setJdbcBatchStyle();
    processCompletedBindRow(currentRank + 2, currentRank > 0 && sqlKind.isPlsqlOrCall());
    currentRank++;
  }
}

final void setJdbcBatchStyle() throws SQLException {
  if(m_batchStyle == 1){
        SQLException sqlexception =    DatabaseError.createSqlException(getConnectionDuringExceptionHandling(), 90, "operation cannot be mixed with Oracle-style batching");
        sqlexception.fillInStackTrace();
        throw sqlexception;
    } else{
        m_batchStyle = 2;
        return;
    }
}
```

So, they realy check mixing of batch modes for instance of OraclePreparedStatement