# java.sql.SQLException: operation cannot be mixed with Oracle-style batching

Tags: sql, jdbc, oracle11g, batching

I'm not really sure about the mixing JDBC and Oracle batching... I read that I can't mix it on one instance of `preparedStatment` ... because of: [Oracle Update Batching Models - Using both batching models in same application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976770/oracle-update-batching-models-using-both-batching-models-in-same-application)

But I also find something saying that it can't be mixed even in a single application... http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/java.920/a96654/oraperf.htm

So know I'm not sure where the problem is...

I create a new prepared statment in each call of function:

```
public void functionCall(int Id)

    PreparedStatement insStm = null;
    String featureName = "";
    String featureTypeName = "";

        String sql = "BEGIN insert into " + TABLE_FEATURE_INSET + " values (?, ?, ?, ?); EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN IF SQLCODE != -1 THEN RAISE; END IF; END;";
        insStm = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);

        for(xxx)
            for (yyy) {
                for (zzz) {
                    insStm.setObject(1, TypeName);
                    insStm.setObject(2, tableName);
                    insStm.setObject(3, sourceId);
                    insStm.setObject(4, Id);
                    insStm.addBatch();
                }
            }

            // per feature
            insStm.executeBatch();
        }
        statement .close();
}
```

And then I sometimes get an error...:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed: operation
>   cannot be mixed with Oracle-style batching

Maybe is problem that `prepareStatment` can be from same connection? I'm really  not sure about this.

Can somebody help me? Thanks

**EDIT:**
That error is caused by this call: insStm.addBatch();

Comment: Did you use `((OracleConnection)conn).setDefaultExecuteBatch(..)` on your connection (or connection property `defaultBatchValue` or similar properties in the datasource)? That will disallow JDBC standard batching, and uses some kind of internal batching mechanism specific to the Oracle driver.

Comment: Yes, we used something like that... So that can cause an error? But I can use ((OracleConnection)conn).setDefaultExecuteBatch(..) and then on some other connection conn2 do a jdbc standard batching whithout a problem right?

Comment: Yes that is the cause, Oracle batching and JDBC standard batching are mutually exclusive. If you have a connection where you don't use Oracle batching (the value is not explicitly set or set to 1), then you can use standard batching.